# Detecting if code is run by hangfire?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I have some tasks that are being executed regularly using Hangfire. Some of the code in my application can both be executed by Hangfire and by user actions. Is there a safe way to detect at runtime whether any part of the code is currently executed by Hangfire or not? One option I looked into was to create a dedicated user in my application, and set up Hangfire to use this one, but I have not found out how I am able to set session state for the Hangfire thread. I use the session object to store information about the currently logged in user, so if I was able to set this to a dedicated system user for when Hangfire is running, that would be all I need.

Comment: Is the call stack different when called by Hangfire?

Comment: I guess it is, yes. I could potentially dig into the stack trace, but it does however not seem like the cleanest way of doing this. Ideally I think I would want to be able to set the session storage, because then I would not need to handle Hangfire actions differently than user-initiated actions. It would just be using a system account that I make sure have the proper privileges